# Android ListView and Child selection

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I am trying to implement a list view for chat messages (like WhatsApp)

I need to implement selection mechanism on the list view such that

i ) Long press on any item should start the list view action mode (Should show 1 item selected, 5 item selectd  etc...)

ii) If the action mode on the list view is on , subsequent clicks on the child views should be discarded the list item should be selected...(Clicking on the image should not open or download the image)

iii) If not in Action mode, clicking on the attachments should open the attachments (Click on the attachment should open or download attachment if no items are selected.. )

Please help...

Comment: I am trying to click on the image view in a list view item. If Action mode is on image view should not handle the click and list view should handle it.....

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ClickInterceptor class which can handle both the view and the list item click listener

```
public class ClickInterceptor implements
       View.OnClickListener, 
       ListView.OnItemClickListener, 
       ListView.OnItemLongClickListener
```

which results in implementing all the different click methods you'll need.

This way, the view and your listview clicklistener/itemclicklistener can accept objects of this class.

Now in the `ClickInterceptor` class, you can write the code that can keep track and decide what to happen, according to the ActionMode state.

Answer (score 0):

public class ChatAttachment extends LinearLayout
{
    private Context mContext ;
    public ChatAttachment(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        init();
    }

```
public ChatAttachment(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    mContext = context;
    init();
}

private void init(){

}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){

    if(ChatListAdapter.mActionModeEnabled){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

}